# Gaussian random noise (complex number in C++)

Tags: c++

I want to generate random noise in c++. The code that I am using is

```
int N=8;    
double N0=5; 
complex<double> NoiseVec[N]; 
complex<double> t;    


for(int i=0; i<N ;i++){
NoiseVec[i] = (complex<double> t(rand(),rand()));
}
```

but it is giving me error. I am not sure where the mistake is

Comment: For Gaussian noise you need `std::nornal_distribution` instead of `rand()`. See the example here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/normal_distribution

Answer (score 3):

The mistake is here:

```
NoiseVec[i] = (complex<double> t(rand(),rand()));
```

I believe you want to create a temporary and assign it to `NoiseVec[i]`; if so, you should change it to:

```
NoiseVec[i] = complex<double>(rand(), rand());
```

---

**Edit0:** Also,

```
int N=8;
complex<double> NoiseVec[N];
```

is not standard C++, even though clang and GCC compile it.

I suggest you use a range-based for loop:

```
#include <complex>
#include <cstdlib>

// Don't do this
//using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::complex<double> NoiseVec[8];
    for (auto& noiseElem : NoiseVec)
        noiseElem = std::complex<double>(std::rand(), std::rand());
}
```

---

**Edit1:** As per [Sebastian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13130048/sebastian)'s comment: to obtain Gaussian random noise, you should use [`std::normal_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/normal_distribution) instead of `std::rand()`.

Comment: Still no Gaussian noise ...

Comment: OP asks why the code fails to compile, even though the title says "Gaussian random noise"

Comment: This you solved, and I had upvoted your answer.